# Bootstrap Button-Switch w/ Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap button-switch element to display the value of a setting. I am having a problem setting the value initially on page load.

What is happening is, I have the NG-model set appropriately, and I know the state of the underlying checkbox is properly set. I've seen it by 'breaking' the css. Additionally, I have a separate checkbox directly below that is set to the value from the ng-model, and I've validated that it's set.

On page load, I'm trying to set the switch's state to the value of the ng-model (true / false). This is not the value of the checkbox, but rather the state of the UI element. The problem is, the only way to manipulate the UI switch state is via the bootstrapSwitch('state', ) function. I tried putting this in document.ready, but my JSON object is not yet returned, so it's always false.

Is there an element or something that I can do to set these values after I've retrieved my JSON data? Something like an on("init") event? Or should I be doing this somewhere else?

```
<div class="make-switch" id="enable-protection" data-on="success" data-off="warning">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAccount.ProtectionSetting.EnableProtection">
</div>
```

Note - I am able to set this value via:

```
$('enable-protection').bootstrapSwitch('status', $('enable-protection'))
```

And I am doing the above when I select an account from a dropdown box.... so I can trigger an list.change event and make the above call.... But I can't get it to set initially on page load. We pass the account number

Comment: Seeing some code would help.

Comment: use a directive to initalize the plugin based on scope model values

Comment: I understand what you're saying... But how / where would the directive be called?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch?